# Creating Multiple Objects of the same object

Tags: java, object, serialization, organization

Hi I am writing a program that stores Tasks that the user types in. Now I have a Task Object class written. I have code for serializing the object Tasks onto a file. I do not know how to create and label the tasks automatically (ex: task1, task2, task3). I need to be able to do this if the user enters several tasks so I can organize them. Basically: how to create and label the tasks automatically, and is serializing the best option for storing and organizing the Tasks?

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Task extends TaskProcessing implements Serializable
{
    //number of the task
   //int taskNumber;
   //how long the task will take to do
   //double lengthOfTask;
   //mm/dd/yyyy date the task is to be worked on
   //String date;
   //low medium high priority
   //String priority;
   //morning, afternoon, evening, night
   //String timeSlot;
   //hh/mm time the task starts
   String time;
   //work/study/personal categories for the task
   //String catagory;
   //reminders
   //String reminder;

  // There some more variables

   public void setTime(String time)
   {
       this.time = time;
   }

   // There some more variables

   public String getTime()
   {
       return this.time;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return new StringBuffer(" Street : ")
       .append(this.time).toString();
   }

}
```

This is the code for storing the objects

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Serializer 
{

public static void serializerTask (String args[]) 
{

   Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
   serializer.serializeTask("1:00");
}

public void serializeTask(String time)
{

   Task task = new Task();
   task.setTime(time);

   try{

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\task.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
    oos.writeObject(task);
    oos.close();
    System.out.println("Done");

   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
```

Comment: You can create multiple objects of same class, not object.

Comment: You can `clone()` an `Object` if the class `implements Cloneable`... :-)

Comment: From the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using FileWriter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of static variable that will act like prefix or suffix for filenames. It should change after beeing used. If you use stati field, all objects of given class will use the exact same field (it is shared between all instances)

```
private static Integer suffix=0; // in declaration

FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\task"+(suffix++)".ser"); // later in code
```

This is not thread safe solution, but to make it thread safe, we need to use `static AtomicInteger` and use its method eg. `getAndIncrement()`. This is equivalent of `suffix++` but in thread safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon the basis laid in the answer by antoniossss:

Give the class an idgenerator and give each instance a unique id. In a crude manner, something like:

```
public class Task extends TaskProcessing implements Serializable
{
     private static final AtomicInteger ID_GENERATOR=new AtomicInteger(0);
     private final int id;
     //.....

     public Task()
     {
         id=ID_GENERATOR.getAndIncrement();
         //...
     }
}
```

And then use that id in the filename for the file to which you write the tasks otherwise you run the risk of overwriting the last saved task every time you save a new task. Also, even if you append all tasks in the same file, it will be hard to read (deserialize) just one task and even harder to update it in the file.

Though really, keep in mind that this way of persisting user-entered data is very crude. You're effectively implementing your own filestore. It can be a good exercise but if it's something more you're most likely better off by using a more suited way of storage such as a database.

Comment: So basically, I would have a file for each task?

Comment: @Josiah L. In the scenario described above, yes.